# How to clear sqlserver cache to get correct execution plan

Tags: sql-server

I had a query that was running slow (2.5 mins) on sqlserver.

I got actual execution plan, and there was a suggestion for an index. I created the index and now execution time is < 2 seconds.

Then we had to restart sql server.

Query went back to being slow (2.5 mins),  again, I looked at execution plan. This time there was a suggestion for a different index!

It would appear that first execution plan index suggestion was taking into account some sort of cached index maybe?

How can I clear cache (if this is the issue) before looking at execution plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptoms suggest parameter sniffing, where the query plan was generated for the initially supplied parameter values but the plan is suboptimal for subsequent queries with different values. You can invalidate the currently cached plan for specific query by providing the plan handle to [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql):

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE(plan_pandle);
```

There are a number of ways to avoid parameter sniffing. If the query is not executed frequently, a recompile [query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) will provide the optimal plan for the parameter values supplied. Otherwise, you could specify an optimize for unknown hint or use the Query Store (depending on your SQL Server version) to force a specific plan or have SQL Server automatically identify plan regression and select a plan.

Comment: Great. Where do I find plan_handle?

Comment: [`sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql).

Comment: Wyy don't they just write it on the Plan!

Answer (score 3):

Dont clear the cache in PRODUCTION environment. It will lead to serious performance issues.

If you want to generate new plan instead of existing plan, you can go for RECOMPILE option as part of stored procedure execution to see whether new index is being considered in the new plan.

```
EXEC dbo.Procedure WITH RECOMPILE;
```

or you can regenerate the execution plan for the procedure, by using the below command. Next time, it will be using the newly generated plan.

```
EXEC sp_recompile `dbo.procedure`
```

If you want to measure performance improvement repeatedly in a test environment, you can go with below clearing approaches:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE -- It will clear the plan cache completely
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS -- It will clear the unchanged data brought from disk to memory.
```

More elegant approach is to write the dirty pages to disk and then issue the cleaning of unchanged data.

```
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
```

Comment: How does FREEPROCCACHE know which plan I want to clear?

Comment: It will clear complete procedure cache. not just your plan. It impacts whole cache.